# Running scalastyle in a SBT multi project build

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin, scalastyle

I've a SBT project on a multi-project build set up.

- root
- sub-projectA (root depends on it)
- sub-projectB (root depends on it)

I'd like to run scalastyle for only a few files within the project, which could be located in any of the three projects. In order to select those files, I'm modifying the `scalastyleSources` from the command line before running `scalastyle` like so:

```
sbt 'set scalastyleSources := Seq(file("app/util/Util.scala"))' scalastyle
```

This runs for `root` correctly upon the file that I'm specifying, but it then runs two more times for sub-projectA and sub-projectB, completely ignoring the files I previously assigned to the `scalastyleSources`.

I'd need a way to either let SBT know that I only want to run scalastyle once with the altered configuration *OR* the ability to ignore a certain project entirely when running the command.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to disable the task in any of sub-projects with `scalastyle := {}`

Also, passing the file names as a command line parameter looks strange. In that case I would use scalastyle without sbt.